# Hot to show that system of nonlinear differential equations doesn't have periodic solutions?

Tags: nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

Suppose we have nonlinear system of differential equations
$$
\frac{d\mathbf x}{dt} = \hat{A}(\mathbf x, \mu)\mathbf x
$$
How to show that it has periodic solutions?

Answer (score 1):

To prove or disprove the existence of periodic orbits in general $n$-dimensional nonlinear dynamical systems is a daunting task; the approach highly depends on the structure of the specific system. There is no general theory.

However, when the system is Hamiltonian (which is a major assumption and introduced a lot of structure), there is work done on the [Weinstein conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein_conjecture), which is highly nontrivial, even in low-dimensional cases.